# Outbound email node not visible in 2011 SP1 HR2

Tags: outbound-email

I have installed Outbound Email and Audience manager, have configured the database access via MSSQL and I am setup with a Tridion Admin user. The problem is, that in the 2011 GUI there is supposed to be an Outbound Email node in certain publications, but I cannot see it. I get no errors in my log and have verified the install.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: check in the Windows Event Logs for possible error message for Outbound Emails - I hope there will be, kindly share them.

Comment: No, nothing appears in the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two possible scenarios:

1. You haven't actually enabled AM/OE in any Publications.
2. Your license doesn't cover Outbound E-mail (or Audience Manager which is required for OE).

To check the first option, edit the Publication properties and check if there is an **Audience Management** tab. If there isn't, the problem is likely with your license.

If it's there, go to that tab and change something (e.g. one of the URLs) and click Save. The Audience Management and Outbound E-mail nodes should then show up in the tree. If they still don't, try refreshing.

Comment: Do you also have a valid Audience Manager license? OE depends on that. If you start any of the AM/OE services, you will likely see the licensing errors in the event viewer.

Comment: Hm, no in my license.xml I only have an Outbound E-mail node.

Comment: OE is built on top of Audience Manager, so you cannot use it without also having a license for AM. You should have received one at the same time; if you cannot find it, contact Support.